# DisplayFor and EditorFor Helpers seem to be showing different Id values?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a really weird one.

I have a master - detail relationship, lets call it Order and OrderItem. On the front page I have a list of Orders and alongside each row I have an "Edit" link which takes me to an edit page.I need to show the Order details at the top and I edit the Order Item details at the bottom.

However the "Id" hidden field for the "Order Item" form is showing the "Order" Id Value. What is even more weird is that DisplayFor shows the correct value and HiddenFor and EditorFor Show the "Order" Id Value.

I am using a View Model to contain the Master and Detail entities for the Razor view which I populate in the controller.

Assume Order# = 16 and OrderItem# = 7

So :

```
@model vmOrder // ViewModel that contains myOrder and MyOrderItems.

@Html.EditorFor(m=>m.myOrderItems.First().Id) // Produce 16
@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.myOrderItems.First().Id) // Produce 16
@Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.myOrderItems.First().Id) // Produce 7 which is correct.
```

I did intend to just return the first record hence "First()" for other reasons. It seems MVC is getting muddled...

Any thoughts. Seems most bizarre to me?

Many thanks,

Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `myOrderItems`?  If it contains the results of a deferred LINQ query, each time you call `First` it will re-evaluate the query.  Depending on how you have your query written, this could cause the value to change.

If myOrderItems is `IEnumerable`, make sure you are calling `ToList` or `ToArray` to force the query to run.

Second, don't call `First` multiple times.  Try something like this.

```
@model vmOrder // ViewModel that contains myOrder and MyOrderItems.

@var first = Model.myOrderItems.First()
@Html.EditorFor(m => first.Id)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => first.Id) 
@Html.DisplayFor(m => first.Id)
```

Comment: Huge thanks for this, and wise words of experience !!! Really appreciated. Will give it a try.